# Fetching blocked by CORS. flight request doesn't pass access control check when fetching google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cors, fetch-api

I want to send data to a google cloud function from my chrome webbrowser (from the dev console). But I am getting stuck. Have tried everything that I can find on google and even ChatGPT.

I keep getting the error:
Access to fetch at 'cloud function link' from origin 'https://chat.openai.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The javascript that I inject in my browser:

```
var data = { key: 'value' }; 
fetch('https://google cloud function link', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

**EDIT:**: Solved
Up to date Python code for the cloud function, thanks DominicT!
UPDATE: The reason for the CORS failing was due to the GCF (google cloud function) not fully executing because of an error in the last bit (repo.create_file(.....)). If the file already exists in the github respository, the code breaks and thus the CORS as well.

```
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see:
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('test', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    from github import Github

    # First create a Github instance:
    import os
    GIT_TOKEN = os.environ["GIT_TOKEN"]

    # using an access token
    g = Github(GIT_TOKEN)

    # Then play with your Github objects:
    for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
        if repo.name == "chat_gpt_results":
            repo.create_file("test_file_test_funct.txt", "init commit", "file_content ------ ")

    return (repo.name, 200, headers)
```

Comment: Hello @PdB, can try this configuration on HTTP CORS using [Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors#functions_http_cors-python)?

Comment: @DominicT thanks, but had already tried that, without success :(

Comment: @Dominic: SOLVED. I created a new cloud function, this time 2nd gen instead of 1st gen. Used the HTTP CORS as you suggested. Now it's working. Actually I think the issue was that I had forgotten to add the function_framework package to the previous trial and error scripts and that's why it did not work (LOL). Thanks!

Comment: Careful with that `request.method == 'OPTIONS'` check. Not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created 2nd generation Cloud Function Version instead of using 1st generation.

Used the [HTTP CORS Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors#functions_http_cors-python).

Imported package function_framework:

```
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see:
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('test', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    from github import Github

    # First create a Github instance:
    import os
    GIT_TOKEN = os.environ["GIT_TOKEN"]

    # using an access token
    g = Github(GIT_TOKEN)

    # Then play with your Github objects:
    for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
        if repo.name == "chat_gpt_results":
            repo.create_file("test_file_test_funct.txt", "init commit", "file_content ------ ")

    return (repo.name, 200, headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this one DominicT. Will mark as solution. SIDENOTE: The reason for the CORS failing was due to the GCF (google cloud function) not fully executing due to an error in the last bit (repo.create_file(.....)). If the file already exists in the github respository, the code breaks and thus the CORS as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here, it seems that it is the ChatGPT domain which does not allow cross origin requests.

You are using the wrong domain for reaching OpenAPI APIs. Here you can find the documentation: https://platform.openai.com/docs/introduction.

If you still want to make requests to this domain from a browser you should create a Google Function to act as a proxy for your requests.

Comment: I  want to send the title + content of a chatgpt conversation to a cloud function,  so that the cloud function can create a github file in a repository. I don't believe there is an openAi API for this specific task. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: What's also strange is that there were occassions when it worked, but could not reproduce that later on..

Comment: Not sure as well an API exists for that case. The only solution I see to access this user informations is to develop a browser extension. You will not have CORS issue in that case.

My first solution using Google Cloud Function as proxy won't work since you need user session.